# Realm taking too long to copy objects to RealmObject

Tags: android, realm

I'm using realm to store a list of Products in my Andorid App. 
So, I receive a produtc's list with about 3k objects. 
And I'm trying to store them like this:

```
@Override
public void saveAll(List<ProductsDomain> domainProducts) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Realm instance = getRealmInstance();

    RealmList<ProdutcsRealm> realmProducts = new RealmList<ProdutcsRealm>();
    try {
        ProdutcsRealm realmProduct = getClasseEntidadePersistencia().newInstance();
        for (ProductsDomain domainProduct : domainProducts) {
            fromDomainToPersistence(domainProduct, realmProduct);
            realmProducts.add(realmProduct);
        }
        instance.beginTransaction();
        instance.copyToRealm(realmProducts);// taking to long, 3k items
        instance.commitTransaction();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        instance.cancelTransaction();
        return;
    }


}
```

So, the realm is taking too much time, something like 20 minutes. Anybody have any idea to get better performace?

**Solved:**
I've found the problem! I was using the same ProductsRealm instance for all iteration. Looks like that Realm dont work well when you try to save a list of multiple references to de same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be faster if you can add the objects to your Realm in `fromDomainToPersistence()`. The `saveAll()` method could be something like:

```
public void saveAll(...) {
    Realm instance = getRealmInstance();
    try {
        instance.beginTransaction();
        for (ProductsDomain domainProduct : domainProducts) {
            fromDomainToPersistence(instance, domainProduct);
        }
        instance.commitTransaction();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

and

```
public void fromDomainToPersistence(Realm r, DomainProduct domainProduct) {
     ProductRealm realmProduct = r.createObject(ProductRealm.class);
     // set the fields' values
}
```

Comment: Yeah, your approach would work and solve the problem. I was using the same instance for every object comming from domain. And when I did try to save, looks like that Realm got into a dead lock or something else.