# Why are single transactions so slow?

Tags: android, realm

!!! FULL EDIT !!!

Because my question was not really well defined and therefore did not address the problem right. With help from the already existing answers I did some more testing and edited this.

### Baseline/Task

Store 10.000 items in two "operations". Keep track of Realm size and the time it takes to finish the whole task.

These items have the following structure:

```
class DbObject() : RealmObject() {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Index
    lateinit var id: String
        private set

    var data: ByteArray? = null
        private set

    var downloadedAt: Long = 0L

    var lastUsed: Long? = null

    constructor(
        id: String,
        data: ByteArray? = null,
        downloadedAt: Long
    ) : this() {
        this.id = id
        this.data = data
        this.downloadedAt = downloadedAt
        this.lastUsed = downloadedAt
    }
}
```

The cleanups in the following code parts will delete older Realm entries to keep a maximum of 5000 items in the Realm.

### Tests

#### Single insertion

Inserts each item individually and does a cleanup after a set cycle (e.g. 5 insertions).

```
fun storeInDb(object: DbObject) {
    Realm.getInstance(DatabaseConfig.REALM_CONFIG).use { realmInstance ->
        realmInstance.refresh()
        realmInstance.executeTransaction {
            it.copyToRealmOrUpdate(object)
            cleanupTick = (cleanupTick + 1) % CLEANUP_CYCLE
            if (cleanupTick == 0) {
                cleanupDb(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Bunch insertion

All 5000 items are stored in one transaction.

```
fun storeListInDb(list: List<DbObject>) {
    Realm.getInstance(DatabaseConfig.REALM_CONFIG).use { realmInstance ->
        realmInstance.refresh()
        realmInstance.executeTransaction { realm ->
            list.forEach {
                realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Batching / Chunk insertion

The items are stored in chunks of about 1000 items.

```
fun storeInDb(list: List<DbObject>) {
    Realm.getInstance(DatabaseConfig.REALM_CONFIG).use { realmInstance ->
        realmInstance.refresh()
        var index = 0
        while (list.lastIndex - index > 1000) {
            storeListInDb(realmInstance, list.subList(index, index + 1000))
            index += 1000
        }

        val rest = list.lastIndex - index
        if (rest > 0) {
            storeListInDb(realmInstance, list.subList(index, index + rest + 1))
        }

        realmInstance.executeTransaction {
            cleanupDb(realmInstance)
        }
    }
}

private fun storeListInDb(realmInstance: Realm, list: List<DbObject>) {
    realmInstance.executeTransaction { realm ->
        list.forEach {
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(it)
        }
    }
}
```

### Test results

```
start: 480kb, end: 832kb, timeTaken: 370.622s    // 5000 individually (cleanup after 5 insertions)
start: 4608kb, end: 5120kb, timeTaken: 2.704s    // 5000 in one transaction (cleanup after whole list was stored)
start: 1664kb, end: 2048kb, timeTaken: 2.519s    // 5000 in chunks of 1000 (cleanUp after whole list was stored)
```

`start`: Realm size after 5000 insertions
`end`: Realm size after 10000 insertions

### Conclusion

Size: More smaller transactions will keep the Realm file smaller.

Time: Bigger transactions will reduce the time (in most cases)

### Question

Still my question now is: Why are single transactions so (god damn) slow? For 5000 items they are about 148 times slower than batching transactions.

Comment: FWIW that's not a Unit Test, it's an Integration Test (might help you googling other ppl talking about this)

Comment: "closing of realm is taking far too long" could you expand on what you mean here, circumstances, expectations etc

Comment: Yeah you're right it really is no Unit test ^^ But that's not important for this problem. I already did some research and found some GitHub issues from 2014 that seem to be fixed. Searching for closing problems did not get me any good results either.

Comment: Because you don't use the result of `copyToRealmOrUpdate` you should use `insertOrUpdate`.
To reduce your realm file size, you just need to use `compactOnLaunch` when setting your realm configuration (https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#faq-large-realm-file-size).

For your question about why smaller transactions are slower, I don't have the answer

Answer (score 1):

reinitializing the same object instance will slow down your process as you did inside `testSize` method

This issue is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211192/realm-taking-too-long-to-copy-objects-to-realmobject?rq=1)

Comment: What I got from that issue is to save multiple objects in one transaction. That decreased the time by half (what seems to take too long either) and almost tripled the size of the realm file. Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a 'question' as such, but I'll point out a couple of things that mean that you are not testing 'time to write N objects' so much as 'doing things N times that create N objects'. There is a difference, and if this forms part of a project (rather than just a test for your interest) then there are ways to speed this up.

1. For every write, you are re-opening the database (i.e. within `storeInDb` you are calling `Realm.getInstance`) and then closing it.
2. You shouldn't **need** to call `.refresh` when you open the realm.
3. Rather than query for the presence of an object and then call `.copyToRealm`, just call `.copyToRealmOrUpdate`.
4. I don't know if it will help, or just cause blocking, but have you tried using `executeTransactionAsync` instead?

As mentioned in the Realm docs, try and make sure you batch operations as much as possible. If you want to add 1000 objects, then add 1000 objects together. As much as trying to keep an abstract view of the database is worthwhile, sometimes the design may need to understand the concept of 'batching' operations.

Comment: Thanks for your tips. I used some of your advice in my  post edit. `1.` I'm calling refresh just to make sure everything is up to date. Is that really wrong? `2.` After some more tests I think re-opening does not affect the operation a lot.

Comment: 1. Probably not *wrong*. Unnecessary though. Don't know if there's a cost - [this post](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4965) discusses it a little. 2. Interesting, I'd have expected a cost with opening and closing.

Comment: I'm so sorry Chris, probably I'm a little over-worked. Closing, at least for many single item transactions is affecting performance. The first time I made the multiple transactions without re-opening did not show any differences for some reason. I just tested both re-opening and re-using again and re-opening seems to take 3 times longer than re-using. But what I can say for 5000 items is that even with re-using, single item insertion takes 30sec longer than batched insertion.